# copy and paste over flash instances

Tags: apache-flex, copy-paste

I have two swf files created using flex. Both swf file have some labels, textboxes and checkboxes. I want to be able to modify the second swf file by copying the labels and textboxes from swf file 1 and pasting them to swf file 2. I do not want to loose the formatting on labels or textboxes when pasting.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I don't think this is going to be possible w/ copy and paste.  You can copy text; but how would you copy checkboxes? You may be able to communicate between the two SWFs using localConnection and somehow serialize your data/layout to send it to the other SWF.  But, I bet it will be complicated.  Are there other technologies that let you copy and paste UI elements such as checkboxes?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did look at the possibility of using localConnection but as you mentioned here its is complicated if I have more than 2 instances of the swf files. The functionality that i have working currently for copying in same instance is that I have HashMap to store the mapping and then the ArrayCollection variable to store the selected fields. This information is then sent over to the paste method I grab the xml for different field widgets, update it with new position, update hashmap with new values.  Works for single instance but want it to work for two different instances.

Comment: You might be able to do this using a native extension http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html if you can use AIR. The trick is to manipulate the system clipbard the way you've been manipulating the instance clipboard.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship - That is for AIR app. Do you know something that can work for webapp?